# Ruby enumeration has unexpected second pass

Tags: ruby, imap, enumeration

This is making me crazy. I'm trying to loop through email messages using ".each do |one_of|…end", but inserting one innocuous statement breaks the enumeration.

Here is an almost-stand-alone snippet. The authentication info is set up immediately preceding, as is the "require net/imap"

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new(IMAP_server)
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', IMAP_login, IMAP_pass)
imap.select(IMAP_folder)
[1,2,3,5].each do |mnum|
#message_ids = imap.search(['SUBJECT', 'NETGEAR R7000 Log']).each do |mnum|
    puts(mnum)
    msg = imap.fetch(mnum, 'BODY[TEXT]')
    msg[0].values[1]['BODY[TEXT]'].each_line do |full_entry|
        line = String.new(full_entry)
        recType = line[/^\[.*\] /]
#       recType = recType.tr('[]','')
        puts recType
    end
    puts
    puts
end
```

It was working (and not) when I was looping through message ID numbers, but I replaced that statement with a literal array to eliminate a potential problem source.

Running it with the ".tr" statement commented out produces expected results, lines like:

```
1
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.9)] 
[DoS attack: FIN Scan] 
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.8)] 
[Admin login] 
[Admin login failure] 
[Admin login] 
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.7)] 
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.5)] 
[Time synchronized with NTP server] 
[Internet connected] 


2
[LAN access from remote] 
[LAN access from remote] 
[LAN access from remote] 
[UPnP set event: Public_UPNP_C3] 
[UPnP set event: Public_UPNP_C3] 
[UPnP set event: Public_UPNP_C3] 
…
```

Now un-comment the ".tr" line, to remove the brackets, and it goes all the way through the first iteration, but then:

```
1
DHCP IP: (192.168.1.9) 
DoS attack: FIN Scan 
DHCP IP: (192.168.1.8) 
Admin login 
Admin login failure 
Admin login 
DHCP IP: (192.168.1.7) 
DHCP IP: (192.168.1.5) 
Time synchronized with NTP server 
Internet connected 
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/jan/bin/MassageNetgear.rb:39:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/jan/bin/MassageNetgear.rb:39:in `each'
        2: from /Users/jan/bin/MassageNetgear.rb:43:in `block in <main>'
        1: from /Users/jan/bin/MassageNetgear.rb:43:in `each_line'
/Users/jan/bin/MassageNetgear.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `tr' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

So, somehow, putting this one statement in is causing the second iteration of `mnum` to fail. It doesn't even print "2" for the second iteration. Line 45 in the traceback is the newly inserted statement, but it doesn't even get that far! Adding another `puts` as the first statement in the inner loop does nothing.

I've done this before to concatenate a bunch of emails containing router log messages, but I then modified that code, and I somehow broke it! I've cut and re-typed the problem statement, thinking there may have been invisibles in there, but I'm using BBEdit, which shows such things.

Please, point out where I'm doing something stupid!

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want the part between the brackets, use a capture group, e.g. `line[/^\[(.*)\] /, 1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nil` prints as an empty string, so it's possible there is actually a last line which isn't matching the regexp and which is printing as an empty string. In that case, `tr` would fail since `nil` actually doesn't have a `tr` method.

You could use a conditional assignment, which will not execute the right-hand side if `recType` is falsy.

```
recType = line[/^\[.*\] /]
recType &&= recType.tr('[]','')
puts recType
```

Or (if you want to actually treat it as an empty string), you can simply unconditionally call `to_s` on it.

```
recType = line[/^\[.*\] /].to_s
recType = recType.tr('[]','')
puts recType
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. It was strange that the preceding `puts` didn't print… possibly due to its being buffered, while the stack trace was just pumped out without buffering.

Comment: They do go to different streams (`puts` to stdout and stack traces to stderr), so there are possible race conditions when printing them.

Comment: Doh! I should have known that... been hacking C for years, but Ruby for days… I'll up-vote you as soon as I get 15 points!

Comment: Glad I could be of help! Happy hacking! Ruby's a wonderful language. :)